# Python javascript builder

Tags: javascript, python, builder

I am trying to make a builder for Javascript code in general with Python. I've tried everything I can think of, but I'm still having a syntax error.
the error is this :

File "test.py", line 12
    exploit = ("var word=prompt("Give a word","");function pal(){if(word===word.split('').reverse().join('')){document.write("hello this is a palindrome
"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is the same as "+word)}else{document.write("Error 504(Not a palindrome)...hello this is not a palindrome
"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is not the same as "+word)}}pal();")
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I was thing to convert the ("javascript code") to a string but not working advices? thanks sorry if my question wasnt clear

My code:

```
import time as t
from os import path


def createFile(dest):

  date=t.localtime(t.time())

##Filename=month+date+year
name="%d_%d_%d.js"%(date[1],date[2],(date[0]%100))

exploit = ("var word=prompt("Give a word","");function pal(){if(word===word.split('').reverse().join('')){document.write("hello this is a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is the same as "+word)}else{document.write("Error 504(Not a palindrome)...hello this is not a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is not the same as "+word)}}pal();")

s = str(exploit)


if not(path.isfile(dest+name)):
     f=open(dest+name,'w')
     f.write(s)
     f.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
      createFile("lol")
      raw_input("done!!!")
```

Comment: it's not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: Just look at the syntax highlighting of the line starting with `exploit =`.

Comment: I want to create a file.js that contains all this :

Comment: var word=prompt("Give a word","");function pal(){if(word===word.split('').reverse().join('')){document.write("hello this is a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is the same as "+word)}else{document.write("Error 504(Not a palindrome)...hello this is not a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is not the same as "+word)}}pal();

Comment: Edit your question and put that information in there. Explain *exactly* what is not working out for you. Provide the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: What exactly is the syntax error? There are hundreds, and we must know which one to be able to help you. See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sure this is the error:

Comment: File "test.py", line 12
    exploit = ("var word=prompt("Give a word","");function pal(){if(word===word.split('').reverse().join('')){document.write("hello this is a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is the same as "+word)}else{document.write("Error 504(Not a palindrome)...hello this is not a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is not the same as "+word)}}pal();")
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @javscripters: as you are struggling with the problem and with using SO I have added corrected code to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing you need to escape the quotes within the javascript string that you are assigning to `exploit`. Alternatively you can use a triple quoted string, which is much easier:

```
explioit = '''var word=prompt("Give a word","");function pal(){if(word===word.split('').reverse().join('')){document.write("hello this is a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is the same as "+word)}else{document.write("Error 504(Not a palindrome)...hello this is not a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is not the same as "+word)}}pal();'''
```

That fixes that problem. Note also that you don't need `s = str(exploit)` - `exploit` is already a string.

Also it looks like your indentation is off within the function, not a syntax error in this case, but your function will not work as expected. Here is some cleaned up code:

```
import time
from os import path

def createFile(dest):
    date = time.localtime()

    ##Filename=month+date+year
    name = "%d_%d_%d.js" % (date[1], date[2], (date[0]%100))

    exploit = '''var word=prompt("Give a word","");function pal(){if(word===word.split('').reverse().join('')){document.write("hello this is a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is the same as "+word)}else{document.write("Error 504(Not a palindrome)...hello this is not a palindrome<br>"+word.split('').reverse().join('')+" is not the same as "+word)}}pal();'''

    if not(path.isfile(dest+name)):
        with open(dest+name,'w') as f:
            f.write(exploit)

if __name__=='__main__':
    createFile("lol")
    raw_input("done!!!")
```